# Laravel 5 make the routes know that I am an sending Authorized request

Tags: php, laravel-5, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf, laravel-middleware

I am stucked with this problem for a few days. I am making a request from a function inside a controller using the snappy library to convert a part of the page to pdf. My plan is this:

Use this `$snappy->getOutput('http://myapp.com/campaign/21859866de/');` to take a screenshot of the page and convert it to pdf but whenever i use this it's taking a screenshot of the login page.
    - even if it is not good for the app i tried to exclude that routes from       CSRF verification but still login page is showing on the generated pdf :(

Your suggestions will be very much appriciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think what might be happening is that the library is loading the website itself also and its not being logged in what you may have to do is pass a flag and in your page check for the flag and not require a logged in user.

Comment: @Yeak .. thank you for your quick reponse.. can you please be more specific? Is there a function on laravel 5 that you can recommend for me to pass a flag?

Answer (score 0):

In the app/Http/Middleware directory there is a Authenticate.php file

in there you can specify routes that wotn require a login

```
  public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {

    if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {


            //check for specific route to load without needing to log in
            $routeCheck = $request->route()->getActionName();
            if($routeCheck == 'App\Http\Controllers\SomeController@someMethodInController') {
                return $next($request);
            }

            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);

    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

then in your routes you can specify a routes

```
  Route::get('/campaign/{id}/{flag}', 'SomeController@someMethodInController');
```

what this will do is it will check for that route and allow access without requiring a user to be logged in. the {flag} is the flag you can pass and look for

If you dont require a controller to be loaded and you just want to load up a view only then you can just add the following in your routes.php files

```
Route::get('/campaign/{id}/{flag}', function() {
    return view ('whateverview');
});
```

and because your not hitting a controller by doing this then no log in check happens